# OidcClient.LoginAsync in Xamarin.iOS freezes whole application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, openid

I'm using Xamarin Forms. For Xamarin.Android everything works, but with Xamarin.iOS the application freezes on `OidcClient.LoginAsync`. I'm not sure what the problem is. Everything is awaited. Even when I debug this, it just doesn't return anything. The application is just frozen.

```
public async Task<Credentials> Authenticate()
    {
        try
        {
            var client = CreateOidcClient();
            var result = await client.LoginAsync(new LoginRequest());
            return result.ToCredentials();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HelpUtils.LogErrorLocally(ex);
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            return new Credentials { Error = ex.ToString() };
        }
    }
```

Here is browser implementation

```
internal class WebAuthenticatorBrowser : IBrowser
{
    private readonly string _callbackUrl;

    public WebAuthenticatorBrowser(string? callbackUrl = null)
    {
        _callbackUrl = callbackUrl ?? "";
    }

    public async Task<BrowserResult> InvokeAsync(BrowserOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        try
        {
            var callbackUrl = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_callbackUrl) ? options.EndUrl : _callbackUrl;
            var authResult =
                await WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(new Uri(options.StartUrl), new Uri(callbackUrl));
            var authorizeResponse = ToRawIdentityUrl(options.EndUrl, authResult);

            return new BrowserResult
            {
                Response = authorizeResponse
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            return new BrowserResult()
            {
                ResultType = BrowserResultType.UnknownError,
                Error = ex.ToString()
            };
        }
    }

    public string ToRawIdentityUrl(string redirectUrl, WebAuthenticatorResult result)
    {
        var parameters = result.Properties.Select(pair => $"{pair.Key}={pair.Value}");
        var values = string.Join("&", parameters);

        return $"{redirectUrl}#{values}";
    }
}
```

Here is Info.plist subcode with urls

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>authentication</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>projectName:/authenticated</string>
            <string>projectName:/signout-callback-oidc</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Why is the IOS version of my Xamarin login freezing the application?

Comment: Did you add the settings in your info.plist?

Comment: Yes, i will update my question with more code.